# Vue component shown out of the table

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Rows shown by the component `<tr>` are shown out of the table that encapsulates the component. I read the documentation which says use `is=comp`. I tried using it in all `<tr>` tags but did not work.
Is there a way I can show rows from the component inside the table?

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr >
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
   <comp  v-for = "post in all_trans"  v-bind:ip1="post"></comp>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
Vue.component('comp', {
      data: function () {
                return {
                  boolean1: false
                }
            },
        props:['ip1'],
            template: `
                      <tr >
                          <td>{{ip1.created_at}} </td>
                    </tr>
                      `
           })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats

> Some HTML elements, such as ul, ol, table and select have restrictions on  what elements can appear inside them, and some elements such as li, tr, and option can only appear inside certain other elements.

To fix it, you need to use `<tr is="comp"></tr>` instead of `<comp></comp>`